# Um servlet pode enviar para duas JSP diferentes?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, request

Minha página `index.jsp` utiliza o Servlet e então envia para a `resposta.jsp`.
Na `resposta.jsp` dependendo do botão, eu utilizo o Servlet para usar outra função Java.
Porém não sei como fazer essa utilização.

No meu servlet utilizo:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("resposta.jsp");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

que envia para `resposta.jsp`.

PS: lembrando que ja utilizo um if/elseif para verificar para qual deverá ser mandado, meu problema é não saber se posso criar dois `getRequest` ou algo assim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não precisa criar dois objetos de RequestDispatcher, você pode criar a variável que armazena a referência do objeto primeiro e depois você cria o objeto dentro do if. Exemplo:

```
RequestDispatcher rd;
if (/*condicao*/) {
    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("resposta1.jsp");
}
else {
    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("resposta2.jsp");         
}
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Mas se por um acaso você criar dois objetos diferentes, ele apenas vai deixar a referência do primeiro de lado. Exemplo:

```
RequestDispatcher rd;
rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("resposta1.jsp");
rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("resposta2.jsp");         
rd.forward(request, response);
```

ele vai mandar para `resposta2.jsp` e o primeiro objeto criado será desconsiderado.

Comment: deu certo o exemplo que você me passou. Mas tenho um problema agora. Tenho um IF e ELSE IF e os dois mandam pra mesma pagina só que com valores diferentes, porém se a pessoa entra na opção do if(mostra o resultado) e a pessoa volta a página e tenta a opção do else if, nao funciona. Sabe o que posso fazer?

Comment: @Pacíficão to voltando de férias agora, já que dou uma olhada nisso

Comment: @Pacíficão cara, deixei sua pergunta cair no esquecimento, rs.. Foi mal. Vc já resolveu?

Comment: já sim.. de todo jeito, obrigado pela preocupação.

Answer (score 2):

Como você está fazendo um forward em um jsp e não na servlet, você pode usar jstl ao invés de java puro, assim:

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${condicao}">
    <jsp:forward page="/url1.jsp" />
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <jsp:forward page="/url2.jsp" />
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Lembrando que precisa adicionar a biblioteca do jstl e a directive taglib com a uri.